# Why do we have $\frac{L'}{L}(1+r+it) \ll \frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(1+r)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I am currently reading *Ten Lectures on the Interface Between Analytic Number Theory and Harmonic Analysis.* 
On page 166, it states

$\frac{L'}{L}(1+r+it) \ll \frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(1+r) \ll \frac{1}{r}$

1. Why is this true?

2.(Here should I assume $\frac{L'}{L}(1+r+it)$ refers to $\frac{L'}{L}(1+r+it, \chi)$?

Comment: $\displaystyle\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Lambda(n) n^{-s}$ is a Dirichlet series with non-negative coefficients. $\displaystyle\frac{-L'(s,\chi)}{L(s,\chi)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n)\Lambda(n) n^{-s}$ where $|\chi(n)| \le 1$

Comment: Thanks @reuns !!